# Propagation issue with jQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a javascript / jquery simple game actioned by two buttons.

**Button 1: "Play".** The game is played ten times, and increments using a variable that I store in local storage. If the increment matches a random number between one and 10, then `console.log("match!")`, otherwise `console,log("no match")`;

**Button 2: "Restart the game".** Once the increment is bigger than 10, then the game starts over by clicking the button.

The problem is, if you look into the console, that the second time you play the game, the game jumps by two increments at a time. The third time, by three increments... Why is that? There is a propagation issue here. How do I solve it?

[Jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/2wh9tgpc/1/). Code I paste below, as it's very small:

```
start_game_over()

function start_game_over(event) {
  $("#button1").show();
  $("#button2").hide();

  localStorage.setItem("progress", 0)

  $("#button1").on("click", function() {

    if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) < 11) {

      var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
      console.log(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")));
      if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) === random_number) {
        console.log("match!")
      } else {
        console.log("no match")
      }

      localStorage.setItem("progress", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) + 1);

    } else {
      $("#button1").hide();
      $("#button2").show();
      $("#button2").on("click", function() {
        start_game_over();
      });

    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `start_game_over` you assign an event listener to the button click, but you never remove it, so when you call the function again it attaches a new one. restructuring the code a bit to handle the clicks outside of that function would be a good idea.

```
function start_game_over(event) {
  $("#button1").show();
  $("#button2").hide();

  localStorage.setItem("progress", 0)
}
$("#button1").on("click", function() {

    if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) < 11) {

      var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
      console.log(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")));
      if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) === random_number) {
        console.log("match!")
      } else {
        console.log("no match")
      }

      localStorage.setItem("progress", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) + 1);

    } else {
      $("#button1").hide();
      $("#button2").show();

    }
  })
$("#button2").on("click", function() {
    start_game_over();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your event listeners inside a function, so every time the function is called, you are creating a new listener. Put them out of the function and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear your `$('#button1')` event at the end by using `$('#button1').off('click');`. This will clear the event listener you create every time in your function.

SE doesn't allow `localStorage` so run this on JSFiddle or local machine.

---

```js
start_game_over()

 function start_game_over(event) {
   $("#button1").show();
   $("#button2").hide();

   localStorage.setItem("progress", 0)

   $("#button1").on("click", function() {

     if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) < 11) {

       var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 0) + 0);
       console.log(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")));
       if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) === random_number) {
         console.log("match!")
       } else {
         console.log("no match")
       }

       localStorage.setItem("progress", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("progress")) + 1);

     } else {
       $("#button1").hide();
       $("#button2").show();
       $("#button2").on("click", function() {
         $("#button1").off("click");
          $("#button2").off("click");
         start_game_over();
       });

     }
   })
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Play</button>
<button style="display:none" id="button2">Restart the Game</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time you invoke `start_game_over` you are *adding* additional click handlers to `#button1` and `#button2`. What you want to do is set up the click handlers *once* and use a function to reset your game state when `#button2` is clicked (or just reset the game state in `#button2`'s callback). For example:

```
var $button1 = $('#button1');
var $button2 = $('#button2');

var start_game_over = function () {
    $button1.show();
    $button2.hide();
    localStorage.setItem('progress', 0)
};

$button1.on('click', function () {
    var progress = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('progress'), 10 /*always include radix!*/);
    if (progress < 11) {
        //... game logic here
    } else {
        $button1.hide();
        $button2.show();
    }
});

$button2.on('click', function () {
    start_game_over();
});
```